# Mongoid's .includes() Not Populating Relations

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am using Mongoid v4.0.2, and I'm running into an interesting issue using `.includes()`.  I have a record that represents invoices, who has a list of charges.

I want to query for a single invoice and have the charges be populated after I run the query.  [According to the docs](http://mongoid.github.io/en/mongoid/docs/querying.html) (search for "Eager Loading"), I should be able to do something like this to have Mongoid populate the charges:

```
Invoice.includes(:charges).find_by({ _id: <objectId> })
```

When I get the record back the charges are still showing up as a list of ObjectId's, and removing the `.includes()` seems to have no effect one way or another.  I've verified each charge exists in the record I'm querying for, so I'm confused why they aren't populating.

I believe I have the data models set up correctly, but I'll include them here for completeness.

```
class Invoice
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :charges

  field :status, type: String
  field :created, type: Time, default: -> { Time.now }
end

class Charge
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :created, type: Time, default: -> { Time.now }
  field :transactionId, type: String

  field :category, type: String
  field :amount, type: Float
  field :notes, type: String

  belongs_to :invoices
end
```

Comment: Should be `belongs_to :invoice` (singular), but that's probably just a typo in your question....

Comment: Nope, it wasn't a typo. It's still not populating after changing the `belongs_to:` value though.

Comment: Did you update the documents in your charges collection after changing the belongs_to statement?

Comment: @MarcoSandrini I'm creating these records in another app, so I'm more trying to match what's already being created in the database.

Comment: where do you store the "foreign_key"? As `invoice_id` in charge or as an array of ids in the invoice model. Mongoid expects the former when marking the relationship as Referenced 1-N

Comment: Reading your question it instead appear that you have the latter. Which means you cannot use mongoid has_many/belongs_to relationship for it, which also explains why eager loading does not work

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Yeah, I did not have a `foreign_key` set.  I've added the foreign key and set it on the charges I'm looking at, however they still aren't populating as expected.  I'm going to do a bit of research into it to ensure I'm setting up everything correctly, then I'll update the OP.  (Sorry, not trying to be a help vampire here.)

Comment: By foreign key I actually meant the field having the id of the other model. If you cannot change the invoice documents to have a `change_id` field, you cannot use mongoid relationship.

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Ahh, I see.  Yes, Invoices have a `charges` key that contains a list of ObjectId's, which corresponds to the _id's of the Charges.

Comment: Which means you should not use the mongoid relationship in your model, but simply define those fields "by hand" in the models and resolve those ids manually after your main query

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Thanks for the help!  I've got some digging to do on this, as this still isn't working out as I expect (even when moving the reference from `charges` to `charge_id`).  I can comment back here when I figure out what went wrong so you can post an answer, I feel like you deserve it after hand-holding me for so long!

Answer (score -1):

There is no reason to use `includes` if you are only finding one document. Just find the document and then access the relation. Either way, 2 database requests will be issued.

The only time `includes` provides a performance increase is when you are loading multiple relations for multiple documents, because what Mongoid will do is load the queried documents, go through and gather all of the ids that should be queried for all of those documents and then query for all relations as one database call using the `:id.in => ids` feature. In your case, there is no point to do this.

Comment: Not really an answer, but OK.